# WCF WebService with warnings and InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, wcf, magento, asp.net-core

I am currently trying to connect my ASP-NET Core 2 application to Magento's API (WSDL v2), but keep receiving the following errors:
*Doesn't matter which method I call, even the `new PortTypeClient().loginAsync(username, password);` throws that, with this random endpoint name `salesOrderShipmentAddComment`.

> InvalidOperationException: The operation
>   'salesOrderShipmentAddComment' could not be loaded because it
>   specifies \"rpc-style\" in \"literal\" mode, but uses message contract
>   types or the System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message. This combination is
>   disallowed -- specify a different value for style or use parameters
>   other than message contract types or
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message.

However, using SoapUI, postman or importing with framework 4.6, it works perfectly.
Using the Magento v1 API it works too, but I don't want to use this version.

During the import in asp-net core, I also recieve those warnings (importing v1 doesn't shows any warning):
[image]

I'm almost creating a new 4.6 application, hosting it separately to work as a bridge between my application and Magento, even if it hurts my performance and architeture.

This is how I'm doing the import:
[image]
*Obs: In `Data Type Options`, I also tried checking different options, and selecting other data types.

Anything would help...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Same here on Linux, sotnet, svcutil and latest .NET Core. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not a good solution, @nielo... I've created a 4.6 .Net application to work as an abstraction layer, reading XML from WSDL, and returning JSON.

Comment: So you confirm that this isn't fixed in 2.1?

Comment: Can't confirm... I may try later, hope it works. Did that upgrade worked for you?

Comment: Update itself worked, but is months ago. WCF does throw above exception :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem.  Make sure you update your Nuget Packages to 4.5.3.   After, works correctly for me.

Comment: Which package should be at 4.5.3? The workaround has already been made (Another .Net 4.6 API to make the communication), but it's always good to know how to fix that.

Comment: I think Chris means the System.ServiceModel packages. I am using version 4.5.3 of these packages and I am still getting the error. Did you fix the issue Bruno? I really don't want to call a .NET framework class library!

Comment: I got this error on new netcoreapp2.2 project, and resolved it with update of nuget packages(System.ServiceModel.*) from 4.4.0 to 4.5.3

Answer (score 6):

Indeed updating the following packages to version 4.5.3 seems to resolve the issue:

System.ServiceModel.Duplex

System.ServiceModel.Http

System.ServiceModel.NetTcp

System.ServiceModel.Security

Seems like 4.4.4 version of those packages are installed by default, while adding WCF service reference via VS 2017 15.9.4 UI

Answer (score 1):

Just update System.ServiceModel.Http to 4.5.3

Answer (score 0):

According to
https://ozguradem.net/english/coding/2018/11/06/soap-services-with-dotnet-core/

Open .csproj file and edit following packages minimum version like these

```
 <ItemGroup>
       <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.5.*" />
       <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.5.*" />
       <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.5.*" />
       <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.5.*" />
   </ItemGroup>
```